# Opaque white status bar in iOS7

Tags: ios, uikit, statusbar

First off, I'm aware that the two well know ways of modifying the status bar are

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

However, with the default style, the status bar has black text with a clear (or translucent white - I can't tell) background.  A view in my application slides up at certain points, and it is viewable through the status bar.  Is there a way to make the status bar background an **opaque** white color?

Thanks

Comment: you should adjust your views' frames/constraints instead

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by creating a Base View Controller that each VC inherits from, and adding the following to `viewDidLoad`:

```
   //Make status bar opaque
CGRect blocker = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20);
ColoredLineSegment *blockerView = [[ColoredLineSegment alloc] initWithFrame:blocker]; //ColoredLineSegment is just a colored in rect
blockerView.color = [UIColor whiteColor];

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:blockerView];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] bringSubviewToFront:blockerView];
```

Comment: I dunno why this is not selected as the correct answer. Just a warning, this will set notification bar white for all of your view controllers, even if you added it in just one (Probably due to UINavigationVC), so remember to hide it when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in AppDelegate.m :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255 green:255.0/255 blue:255.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

It should work !

Comment: Nope.  I tried "View-controller based status-bar appearance" as both true and false.  When it's true, the area that would be the status bar is just black.  When it's false, nothing changes.